# Javascript: Replace anchor with title

Tags: javascript, anchor, title

Is there a way to replace the text in the anchor with the title text, using javascript?

```
 <a href="#" title="3pk Cotton Boxer Shorts (13 - 14 Years)">3pk Cotton Boxer Short...</a>
```

Comment: Gather all the link tags with [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName), iterate with a [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Statements#Loop_Statements) of your choice over them and replace the [nodeValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.nodeValue) with the `title` attribute

Comment: @Andreas You probably meant `firstChild.nodeValue`. And this will only work if there are no `<span>`s etc. in the anchor text. Using `innerHTML` is better.

Comment: @Imp It was ment as a "how to" not as a 100% perfect solution. Otherwise I had posted it as one :) With `innerHTML` you're probably right :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this to all your links, try this:

```
var link = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i =0;i<link.length;i++) {
    link[i].innerHTML = link[i].title;
}
```

**[​jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/GNn24/1/)**.

Comment: how would this work if i just wanted to target anchors with a class?

Comment: You could compare `link[i].className` to the class you want to compare it against.

Answer (score 2):

Why, of course there is. Just set the `innerHTML` property of the anchor equal to the `title` property.

I'm curious, though: why don't you have the correct text in the first place?

Comment: exactly! I was also thinking the same :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var links = document.links;

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
    links[i].innerHTML = links[i].attributes['title'].value;
```

Comment: Don't use `for (var ... in ...)` for `arrays`. It's for `objects` and nothing else.

Comment: @Andreas Aargh! Of course, I didn't realize what I was doing. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `textContent` property:

```
var anchor_list = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); // or however you'd like to select the target <a>'s
for(var i = 0; i < anchor_list.length; ++i) {
    var a = anchor_list[i];
    if(typeof a.textContent != "undefined") {
        a.textContent = a.title;
    } else {
        a.innerText = a.title; // old IE support
    }
}
```

`innerHTML` might not perfrom as expected if you have angle brackets in your title, since it could be parsed as HTML.